# keep radio button values and set default checked

Tags: php, forms, validation, radio-button

I have a form with a radio button group. I want to set 'checked' as default the second radio button, and also keep the value after submitting form if user clicks on the first one.

Note that I'm using the `<span class="custom-radiobutton"></span>` for style the radiobuttons, with a lower `z-index` than the real `<input type="radio"`, which has `opacity:0`.

**This is a snippet of my code:**

```
<div class="group-wrapper">
  <div class="radiobutton-wrapper boolean">
    <span class="custom-radiobutton"></span>
    <input type="radio" id="hosting-1" name="hosting[]" value="1" class="w100" <?php if ((isset($_POST['hosting'])) && ((isset($_POST['hosting'])) == 1)) {echo 'checked="checked"';}; ?> /> 
    <label for="hosting-1">Sí</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radiobutton-wrapper boolean">
    <span class="custom-radiobutton"></span>
    <input type="radio" id="hosting-2" name="hosting[]" value="0" class="w100" <?php if ((!isset($_POST['hosting'])) || ((isset($_POST['hosting'])) == 0)) {echo 'checked="checked"';}; ?> /> 
    <label for="hosting-2">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Additional info:**

- I'm using HTML5.
- I'm validating the form with PHP (I want to keep this, even if I know maybe is better jQuery+PHP validation).
- I have noticed that I need two clicks to select the first radio button. This only occurs from original state. After this, It works with one click, as expected.

I'm expending a lot of hours trying to figure out what's wrong, so any help will be very appreciated.
Cheers,

Comment: You don't need to do checked="checked" for a radio button, you can just use checked.  EX. <input type="radio" id="hosting-2" name="hosting[]" value="0" class="w100" checked>

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" id="hosting-1" name="hosting[]" class="w100"  checked="checked" /> 1
```

try this in your code.

for example:

```
<tr>
    <td><br><b>Reservation Handling :  <span style="color:#FF0000">* &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td><br><input type="radio" name="reservation" value="Delighted" required> Delighted<br></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="reservation" checked="checked" value="Satisfied"> Satisfied</input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="reservation" value="Dissatisfied"> Dissatisfied</input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="reservation" value="N/A"> N/A</input></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your logic.  You're using isset twice.

```
<input type="radio" id="hosting-1" name="hosting[]" value="1" class="w100" <?php if ((isset($_POST['hosting'])) && ((isset($_POST['hosting'])) == 1)) {echo 'checked="checked"';}; ?> />
```

You're essentially saying does isset equal 1, which in your case will always be true if $_POST['hosting'] has a value.

You should do this

```
<input type="radio" id="hosting-1" name="hosting[]" value="1" class="w100" <?php if (isset($_POST['hosting']) && $_POST['hosting'] == 1) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />
```

Comment: I edit my logic as you noticed me (thanks!), but radiobuttons still have not any option marked as checked when I load my form. This is my headache.

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST['hosting'] has a value?

Comment: I'm not sure @ Robbert, because I coded:

`echo "hosting: " . (boolean)$hosting ."<br>";
echo "domain: " . (boolean)$domain ."<br>";`

...and I don't see any value printed when I submit. Maybe is not the correct way to test it?

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST,true) . "</pre>";`  This will show you everything in $_POST.

Comment: I have the solution guys! This is the code:

In the first radiobutton (not checked by default):
`<?php if (isset($_POST['hosting']) && $_POST['hosting'][0] == 1) {echo 'checked';} ?>` ...and for the second radiobutton, (checked by default): `<?php if ( (isset($_POST['hosting']) && $_POST['hosting'][0] == 0) || (!isset($_POST['hosting'])) ) {echo 'checked';} ?>`

Comment: However, I still have to click twice on the radiobuttons to change their checked state. I think I need some jQuery 'click' event in order to it work properly...